# Unit testing of websocket application by sinon.js

Tags: javascript, sockets, unit-testing, websocket, sinon

I have tried to do unit testing for a web socket application using sinon.js,

One of the users on github of [**sinon**](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/174), did this, but I am not able to understand how it does help to unit test websocket applications for validating the received data which was sent to fake server.

```
var dummySocket = { send : sinon.spy()};
sinon.stub(window, 'WebSocket').returns(dummySocket);
dummySocket = new WebSocket('ws://html5rocks.websocket.org/echo');
dummySocket.onopen();
dummySocket.onmessage(JSON.stringify({ hello : 'from server' }));
// You can assert whether your code sent something to the server like this:
sinon.assert.calledWith(dummySocket.send, '{"the client":"says hi"}');
```

**My questions are**

- How can I receive the same data from fake server which have been sent to server earlier.
- How can I send data to fake server by using `send` method of fake socket object(eg:- `socket.send()`)?
- How can I get data from server on `dummySocket.onmessage = function (msg){}`

With **sinon.js**, I could not get the any process to  create fake **websocket** object like for fake `XMLHttpRequest` and `server` by using respectively `useFakeXMLHttpRequest()` and `fakeServer.create()`

**Is there any process to achieve this on sinon.js?**

Comment: The github user suggested something and clearly stated he doesn't know if it even works (Hint: It doesn't).

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? if so, Please post your findings

Comment: I don't know if this might help you, but I wrote a simple npm module that acts as a wrapper for a socket.io server. When testing this [module](https://github.com/danillouz/socket-io-server/blob/master/test/socket.js) I didn't use sinon, but the socket.io Client to send/receive data for testing purposes. If this is what you need, I could elaborate my approach in an answer.

Comment: You might want to take a look at mock-socket, it seems to do what you're wanting: https://github.com/thoov/mock-socket

Comment: You could a fake `XMLHttpRequest ` to imitate the Socket request and when it returns it calls `onmessage`. But this wont test the actual web socket connection but rather the web socket flow. So in the case you want to test the actual connection, something like what @MichaelBleigh suggested might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would do `ws = sinon.createStubInstance(WebSocket)`, but this isn't possible since properties on the WebSocket.prototype throw exceptions when reading them.  There are two ways around this.

1. You could add a `useFakeWebSocket` to sinon to overwrite `WebSocket`.  This would be similar to what `useFakeXMLHttpRequest` does to XMLHttpRequest.
2. Duck type out a `WebSocket` object by iterating over the prototype.

   ```
   beforeEach(function () {
       var ws = {};
       for (var prop in WebSocket.prototype) {
           ws[prop] = function () {}; // some properties aren't functions.
       }
   });
   ```

If you wanted to implement a mock echo WebSocket server so that you can test your event handlers, you could do that with this:

```
var ws;
beforeEach(function () {
    ws = {
        send: function (msg) {
            this.onmessage({ data: msg });
        },
        onmessage: function (e) {
            // stub
        }
    };
});
it('should echo', function () {
    var spy = sinon.spy(ws, 'onmessage');
    ws.send('this is a test');
    assertEquals(spy.args[0][0].data, 'this is a test');
});
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.